# What does each item card do?

Tags: hyrule-warriors

I just started playing adventure mode in Hyrule Warriors and I'm slightly confused on what each item does. For example I tried used a compass to find a hidden area and it was under a rock so I tired to use the bombs and nothing happened.

So what can each item card do and also do item cards respawn on the adventure map?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/185386/how-does-the-compass-work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following is a list of cards available in Adventure Mode, along with a description of each:

[image: Compass] **[Compass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meKTO.jpg)**: Use this while searching to identify where an Item Card can be used

[image: Candle] **[Candle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmMr7.jpg)**: Use this on trees to uncover hidden stairways

[image: Bomb] **[Bomb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmMr7.jpg)**: Use this on walls to uncover hidden caves

[image: Ladder] **[Ladder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Cedi.jpg)**: Use this to move across a single space of water

[image: Bracelet] **[Power Bracelet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Cedi.jpg)**: Use this on heavy rocks and tombstones to uncover hidden stairways

[image: Water Bomb] **[Water Bomb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxH7b.jpg)**: Use this on submerged rocks to destroy them

[image: Digging Mitts] **[Digging Mitts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxH7b.jpg)**: Use this on soft earth to uncover hidden stairways

[image: Bow] **[Ice Arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYYs8.jpg)**: Use this on circles of flame to uncover hidden stairways

[image: Raft] **[Raft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbdyW.jpg)**: Use this on piers to cross to the opposite shore

[image: Hookshot] **[Hookshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbdyW.jpg)**: Use this on distant targets to pull yourself to them

[image: Recorder] **[Recorder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuCRT.jpg)**: Use this on a small body of water to reveal secrets and enemies

[image: Harp] **[Goddess Harp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBTRA.jpg)**: Use it on Goddess Butterflies to make Gossip Stones appear

*Note:* Couldn't find exact images for all of them, but hopefully it helps show which item is which.

*Edit:* Click item names to see the loading screen description for that card along with in-game image.

Comment: Does the in-game icon for the Ice Arrow include the Arrow itself as well (so it looks like a bow and arrow)?

Comment: @Reafexus Yes.  The arrow is pointing up and it to the left of the bow.